# Unable to import drawArc(), drawRect(0, etc on Android Studio

Tags: android, canvas, import, drawing

I am a beginner in Jetpack Compose. I have been studying using different examples and sample codes. One in particular I have been having a problem with. It's frustrating.

Here's the code (from https://developersbreach.com/custom-shape-animations-pulsating-circles-canvas-compose/)

```
@Composable
fun AnimateCircle() {

    // Initial float value for animation start.
    val animateCircle = remember { Animatable(0f) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        // Animation properties
        LaunchedEffect(animateCircle) {
            animateCircle.animateTo(
                targetValue = 1f,
                animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                    animation = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000,
                        easing = LinearEasing
                    ),
                    repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
                )
            )
        }

        // Draw arc in canvas which forms animated circle, repeatable.
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            drawArc(
                color = Color(0xFF302522),
                startAngle = 45f,
                sweepAngle = 360f * animateCircle.value,
                useCenter = false,
                size = Size(80f, 80f),
                //style = Stroke(16f, cap = StrokeCap.Round)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason it will not let me import drawArc. I have androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas up there.

Tried drawRect, drawCircle, etc. All the same thing. I expected the drop down list to have import option.

This is what I got.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Size
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.core.Animatable
import androidx.compose.animation.core.LinearEasing
import androidx.compose.animation.core.RepeatMode
import androidx.compose.animation.core.infiniteRepeatable
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.PaintingStyle.Companion.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.animatecircle3.ui.theme.AnimateCircle3Theme
```

Comment: Looks like [`drawArc()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/DrawScope#drawArc(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset,androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawStyle,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.BlendMode)) is now in `DrawScope` class, implemented in `androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics` artifact since 1.0.0-alpha09 (December 16, 2020). The tutorial seems outdated.

Comment: Consider [edit]ing the question and listing the library dependencies to let us know whether you're using the same dependencies as in the tutorial or not.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there another way to draw an arc?

Answer (score 1):

```
// change this
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas
// with this  
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
```